# How to set bold title in Kivy Popup

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need to set a bold title in Popup. How I can do this?

I tried to do this in the .kv file

```
<InfoPopup>:
    title: '[b]{}[/b]'.format(root.title)
    size_hint: None, None
    size: '400dp', '260dp'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: root.message
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'
            halign: root.message_halign
            padding_x: root.message_padding_x
            markup: True
```

But it occurs error

My Popup python code:

```
class InfoPopup(FormPopup):

    OPTION_OK = 'ok'

    message = StringProperty()
    message_halign = OptionProperty(
        'center', options=['left', 'center', 'right', 'justify']
    )
    message_padding_x = NumericProperty()
    text_ok = StringProperty('Ok')

    def _handle_keyboard(self, window, key, *largs):
        if key == 13 or key == 32:
            # Keys "enter" and "spacebar" are used to confirm
            # Key "esc" will dismiss popup by default
            self.submit_data(self.OPTION_OK)
            return True
        return super(InfoPopup, self)._handle_keyboard(window, key, *largs)
```

And call the Popup

```
popup = InfoPopup(title='Book metadata error' if title is None else title,
                  message=str(message),
                  message_halign='left')
popup.open()
```

Comment: The default `Popup` in `kivy` doesn't let you do so (atleast not upto v2.0.0). You can set `title_font` to change it. Or, you can define your own popup.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Kivy docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#kivy.uix.popup.Popup.title_size), I think the only way is to set a larger font size for the Label.

`title_size` is a `NumericProperty` and defaults to ’14sp’. Try setting it to a larger value.